# div layout as columns

Tags: css, html

i have the following code:

see in http://jsfiddle.net/bniya_dev/SYPNC/2/

```
<div>
    <div id="mainHeader">
        <div id="details1">
            <span>details1</span>
        </div>
        <div id="details2">
            <span>details2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="header">
        <span>header </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
div#details1
{
    float:left; width:100px;

}
div#details2
{
 float:right;

}
```

I want it to look like the following picture:
[image]

What style I should set?

I want it to work in all browsers even mobile browsers

http://jsfiddle.net/bniya_dev/SYPNC/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

You need to clear `floats` before header.

```
.clr{clear:both;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SYPNC/20/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial ;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 65px;
}
div#mainHeader {
    width: 777px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: aqua;
    text-align: right;
}
div#details1 {
    width: 620px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: #ED1C24;
    float: left;
}
div#details2 {
    width: 157px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: #22B14C;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
div#header {
    text-align: left;
}
```

[This is the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SYPNC/22/)

Maybe you should change the font by yourself (*^__^*)...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/SYPNC/9/
This should match your requirements. You can still adjust the width of your `header1/header2`

Answer (score 0):

Give width for below in percentage according to your requirement

```
div#details1
{
   float:left; width:90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html,css both should be change like bellow

**HTML**

```
<div id="details1"> <span>details1</span>

</div>
<div id="details2"> <span>details2</span>

</div>
<div id="header"> <span>header </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{

    width:500px;
}
#details1 {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
#details2 {
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TVWuQ/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div#details1
{
    float:left; 
    background: red;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: right;

}
div#details2
{
 float:right;
    background: green;
    width: 10%;

}
#header{
    clear: both;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SYPNC/21/)

But better way to markup like this.....

```
<div id="mainHeader">
<div id="details">
<span class="one">detail1</span>
<span class="two">detail2</span>
</div>
```

Then you can `float: right;` to `#details`